# Nginx 404 not found without www

Tags: linux, nginx

I've already confgured in domain panel and the dns zone works withot www but I'm getting nginx error 404 when I try to access my domain whithout www.

There's my nginx settings file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/appico.com.br;
        index index.php index.html;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name appico.com.br  www.appico.com.br *.appico.com.br ;

          location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
             }
```

Comment: I think you don't need "www.appico.com.br". On my server I can access with and without www too. Is anything in `nginx` log?

Comment: @uzsolt I have add `www.appico.com.br ` because I'm hosting 2 sites with 2 different domains

Comment: And the `nginx` logs?